# Why does _.map only return the last item?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, lodash

I am using `_.map` for mapping in my state, but it only returns the last item. In the console I see that the array exists in my state but `_.map` only returns the last item of it.

```js
//-------------this is my reducer------------------------
const INITIAL_STATE = {};
export const PostReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_POSTS: {
      return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

//----------this is my renderPost method ------------------------------

renderPosts = () => {
    return _.map(this.props.posts, post => {
      return (
        <li className="list-group-item" key={post.id}>
          <h3>{post.title}</h3>
        </li>
      );
    });
  };
  
 //---------mapStateToProps------------------------------
 const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {posts: state.posts};
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchPosts})(PostsIndex);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why don’t you use the native array map method?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Because he's iterating over an object. It's hard to say what `posts` actually contain because we don't know the original data but most likely `_.mapKeys` does not generate correct data.

Comment: @Sulthan I wonder if `Object.keys(myObj).map` would work better?

Comment: @evolutionxbox He probably wants to generate an array in the reducer and then just use `map`. It does not make sense to `map` over an object in `render` since the order can change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_.mapKeys(action.payload.data)` actually isnt helpful at all. The iteratee is identity in which case this leads the unnecessary computation.

secondly you have done this `return _.mapKeys(action.payload.data);` so your state is now the value of this which means that instead of

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {posts: state.posts};
};
```

you should do this

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {posts: state};
};
```